com.holdenkarau.spark.testing - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTOREURIS
I have a spark scala application, it uses the below versions.
Dependencies:
org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:jar:3.3.2
org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.12:jar:3.3.2
org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:2.3.9
com.holdenkarau:spark-testing-base_2.12:jar:3.3.2_2.0.1
org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:4.0.0:provided

scala version - 2.12.18
Java version for compiling - 8
mvn version - 3.9.6

When i run "mvn install" the unit tests start to fail with the following error.
*** RUN ABORTED ***

An exception or error caused a run to abort: METASTOREURIS 
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTOREURIS
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.builder(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:177)
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.builder$(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:160)
  at com.walmart.dsi.gg.BaseSpec.builder(BaseSpec.scala:14)
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.sqlBeforeAllTestCases(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:219)
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.sqlBeforeAllTestCases$(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:213)
  at com.walmart.dsi.gg.BaseSpec.com$holdenkarau$spark$testing$DataFrameSuiteBase$$super$sqlBeforeAllTestCases(BaseSpec.scala:14)
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase.beforeAll(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:97)
  at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase.beforeAll$(DataFrameSuiteBase.scala:95)
  at com.walmart.dsi.gg.BaseSpec.beforeAll(BaseSpec.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)

I see that "METASTOREURIS" field is not present in "HiveConf" class(https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java).
What version of hive or holdenkarau libraries should i be using here?

If you run a dependency tree (for test scope), you should be able to see which versions is desired by which library.

The field METASTOREURIS exists in Hive 3.x and later, but not in Hive 2.3.x
use org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:3.1.2
If upgrading Hive is not feasible due to other constraints, you must downgrade the spark-testing-base library to align with Hive 2.3.9
